# On the dynamics of open quantum systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, open-quantum-systems

I was going through the book "The theory of open quantum systems" by Breuer and Petruccione, and I am having problems with convincing myself of equation 3.49. In short, I am reading about Quantum Markovian Processes and Markovian master equations. The system at hand is a joint system formed by a open system $\rho_S$ coupled to an environment described by a density operator $\rho_E$. The following is the equation I am having issues with
$$ W_{ab}(t) = \sum_i^{N^2}F_i(F_i,W_{ab}(t)) \;\;\; (3.49)$$ $$ for\;\;(F_i,F_j)\equiv tr_S(F_i^\dagger F_j)=\delta_{ij} $$
where $F_i$ ($i=1,2,...,N^2)$ form a complete basis of orthonormal operators in the Liouville space corresponding to the Hilbert space $H_S$ ($dim(H_S)=N$) of an open quantum system $\rho_S$. Moreover $F_{N²}=\sqrt{1/N}I_S $, so that $tr_S(F_j)=0$ for $j=1,...,N²-1$.Furthermore we have
$$W_{ab} = \sum_{ab}\sqrt{\lambda_b} \langle\phi_a|U(t,0)|\phi_b\rangle,$$

where $\rho_E = \sum_a \lambda_a |\phi_a\rangle\langle\phi_a|$ is the spectral decomposition of the environment in the joint system $\rho(0) = \rho_S(0) \otimes \rho_E$; where, lastly, the unitary $U(t,0)$ determines the evolution of the total system
$$\rho(t) = U(t,0) (\rho_S(0) \otimes \rho_E) U^\dagger(t,0). $$

For some more context, the operator $W_{ab}$ is introduced in the book to give a representation to the dynamical map $V(t): S(H_S) \rightarrow S(H_S)$, where $$V(t)\rho_S(0)=\rho_S(t) = tr_E (U(t,0) (\rho_S(0) \otimes \rho_E) U^\dagger(t,0)).$$ The way the operator $W_{ab}$ is introduced is by then considering the spectral decomposition of $\rho_E$ which inserted in the expression for $\rho_S(t)$ gives the form of $W_{ab}$ I provided above: which ultimately leads to
$$\rho_S(t) = \sum_{ab} W_{ab} \rho_S(0) W^\dagger_{ab}$$
In synthesis the question is: how am I supposed to interpret the product between $F_i$ and $W_{ab}$ given that they represent operators acting on different spaces with different dimensionality?

Comment: the first equation here is just the decomposition of a vector in an orthonormal basis. In this case the "vector" is an operator, and the basis is made of operators, and the inner product is $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{Tr}(A^\dagger B)$, but the rest doesn't change

Comment: arent $W_{ab}$ and $F_i$ acting on two separate spaces with different dimensions? How am I supposed to interpret the product between the two?

Comment: surely you can supply appropriate context without copy-pasting.  If not why should the community be interested in such a specialized problem?

Comment: you could start by describing what the chapter and section are about, and what additional resources you may have consulted, for instance.  Is it a problem with the notation?  Can you explain the notation?

Comment: @ZerotheHero let me know if there is anything that you'd want me to clarify further. as it is the question makes sense to me and I do not see how to briefly make it more explanatory, but of course this is just my perspective. Let me know what confuses you

Comment: @Zerothehero I will mqke sure to add in some more background :)

Comment: I’m sure it makes sense to you but it also has to make sense to the community if it is to have value to the community. I know this (very nice) book: it’s a valuable resource (plus, Pettrucione is a nice guy), but as currently pitched it is not possible to appreciate your question without diving into pretty gory details of the text.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I have added a short section in the beggining of the question introducing the system at hand. I have also added some more information about dynamical maps at the end of the question. I hope this makes the question clearer to the reader

Comment: why do you say they live in different spaces? By the last equations in the post, $W_{ab}$ acts on the space of the system, and so do the $F_i$, eg by your second equation.

Comment: @glS, from my understanding, $F_i$ is some operator acting on a $N²$-dimensional space, while $W_{ab}$ is acting on space of dimension $dim(H_{S\otimes E})$ (the space of the total system $\rho$) which needs not to have $N^2$ dimensions. Am I wrong to think that?

Comment: @OtiDioti mh no, wait, maybe I see the source of the confusion. Each $F_i$ acts on $H_S$, which has dimension $N$, and so do $W_{ab}$. At the same time, an Hermitian operator on $H_S$ can be thought of as a vector in a real vector space of dimension $N^2$, which is the space of Hermitian operators defined on $H_S$. That's why the basis $\{F_i\}$ contains $N^2$ different elements. But that doesn't change that each operator, being (representable as) an $N\times N$ matrix, acts on $H_S$. You're dealing with two different vector spaces: $H_S$, and $\operatorname{Herm}(H_S)$, do not confuse them

Comment: note that $W_{ab}$ also act on $H_S$. They couldn't act on $H_S\otimes H_E$, or your last equation wouldn't make sense. I don't really know the notation used in the text, but I'm guessing in your third equation, defining $W_{ab}$, the operator $U$ acts in the full space $H_S\otimes H_E$, and the expectation value is understood as only wrt the environment degrees of freedom, hence why $W_{ab}\in{\rm Lin}(H_S,H_S)$.

Comment: actually, sorry, on a second read, the text is decomposing general (not necessarily Hermitian) operators on $H_S$. So the inner product is defined in the *complex* $N^2$-dimensional vector space of all linear operators $H_S\to H_S$. The operators $W_{ab}$ are not Hermitian, but nevertheless can be decomposed using the basis of operators $F_i$. These do not need to be Hermitian either (in fact, you can forget about Hermitianity altogether here, it's not particularly relevant, I only brought it up because I'm used to Hermitian bases of ops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do act on the same space: The $\{F_i\}$ are basis of the Hilbert space of operators acting on $H_S$. The $W_{ab}$ are operators acting on $H_S$: They came from the unitary operator on the whole system + environment Hilbert space, say $H_{SE}$, but after tracing out the environmental degrees of freedom, they act only on $H_S$. The statement of Eq. 3.49 is just a completeness relation for operators in Hilbert space $H_S$.

Seeing the comments, maybe it would also be important to clarify that $N^2$ is not the dimension of the space where the $\{F_i\}$ act on, but rather the number of elements in $\{F_i\}$. This means that the dimension of the Hilbert space of operators (also called Banach space) is of dimension $N^2$.